# How to hide line below firefox navbar?

Tags: css, firefox

I'm trying to make a very basic userChrome.css file to hide this 1 pixel line between the navbar and the current web page.

[image: Screen showing the line I want to hide]

I scrolled and tried all this [original css firefox](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/browser/themes/windows/browser.css) but I can't find what class I have to edit to do that..

Answer (score 0):

Found the tag by stripping down a stylish style piece by piece.

```
#navigator-toolbox > toolbar:not(#toolbar-menubar):not(#TabsToolbar):not(:-moz-lwtheme) {
    margin-bottom: -1px !important;
}
```